# I have set up my domain and secret in my app .env, but i keep getting unable to parse error in mailgun and laravel

Tags: laravel, mailgun

I set up my domain as thus: mg.mydomain.com.ng and my secret also in .env. but when i try to register on my laravel app i get this exception error by guzzlehttp:  InvalidArgumentException
Unable to parse URI: https:///v3/mg.mydomain.com.ng/messages.mime

Comment: I think the problem started after running composer update

Comment: make sure in your `.env` file that any strings that have spaces are enclosed by quotes

Comment: i dont see any strings with spaces, are you suggesting i put the mailgun secret in quotes?

Comment: `https:///` you have 3 slashes there. try with just 2?

Comment: I did not put any slashes, guzzlehttp did that

Comment: okay my bad.... i added http:// to the domain name and everything works fine now

Comment: Please mark the correct answer as accepted or, better yet, close this since it was just a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your url has https:/// in it. Correct that and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

just add the endpoint api.mailgun.net as the triple slash is missing the endpoint

to make it https://api.mailgun.net/domain_name
instead of https:///domain_name

:)